# Strapi. Bulk update on Mysql

Tags: mysql, strapi, bulkupdate

How to do bulk update by Id, in Strapi using mysql database?
I'm trying this

`await strapi.query('logs').update({id_in : [12,13]}, {is_transfered : 1});`

But getting this error

**Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 13 limit 1' at line 1**

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist in update function that is offered by Strapi.

But if you use `strapi.query('logs').model` you will have access to the Bookshelf instance.

And if bookshelf supports this feature, then you will be able to bulk update.

Comment: Thanks, I thought i missed something :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late for you but for the people who need it in the future: You can get mongodb connection and bulk update it yourself.

```js
      const mongodbInstance = strapi.connections.default;

      await mongodbInstance.models.Logs.update({id_in : [12,13]}, {is_transfered : 1}, {multi: true});
```

I've written an article about bulk insert and update here you may find useful: https://kursat.github.io/#/post/2021-01-24-strapi-bulk-insert-and-update.md